# Db2 database creation problem

Tags: sql, database, db2, creation

I've just installed DB2 v8.1.18.980. Now I try to create new database. I'm getting the error with the following sql codes:

```
 sqlcode :  -902 

 sqlstate :  58005
```

Unfortunately the error itself in Russian, as a result, I cannot paste it here. Official site says the following about the problem:

"The statement cannot be processed. The application program is not permitted to issue additional SQL statements. For example, a recovery routine associated with the application program may not issue additional SQL statements.

Programmer response
Rebind the failing application program and try again. If the problem persists, examine your DBRM and make sure it matches your program."

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n902.htm

But, it's not clear to me. Any ideas, what can be wrong and how to resole it?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate if it may be an issue.

Comment: The article you linked to is about DB2 on z/OS, which is different from DB2 on Windows. DB2 8.1 for either is ancient and long unsupported. Windows 7 is an issue because of UAC. If you are going to try to run DB2 8.1, you should use Windows XP or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to is for db2 v9 for z/os, not db2 v8 for Windows. So that's the first problem.

The documentation for v8 has [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/rsql0900.htm) to say about SQL 902:

> A system error (reason code = reason-code) occurred. Subsequent SQL statements cannot be processed.
>
> Explanation:
> A system error occurred.
>
> User Response:
>
> Record the message number (SQLCODE) and reason code in the message.
>
> If trace was active, invoke the Independent Trace Facility at the operating system command prompt. Then contact your technical service representative with the following information:
>
> Problem description
>
> SQLCODE and embedded reason code
>
> SQLCA contents if possible
>
> Trace file if possible.
>
> Federated system users: isolate the problem to the data source failing the request (refer to the Troubleshooting Guide to determine which data source is failing to process the SQL statement) and take the necessary diagnostic steps for that data source. The problem determination procedures for data sources vary, so refer to the applicable data source manuals.
>
> sqlcode: -902
>
> sqlstate: 58005

Which brings us to the second problem: it's asking you to contact IBM and open a ticket, and as far as I know v8 is out of support so it won't be that easy.

I think installing v9, v9.5 or v9.7 would be your best bet, unless you have a really compelling reason to stick with 8.